# Conda create environment with .yml file fails

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, environment

I want to create an exact copy of my current environment in conda. So I am exporting my environment as a env_dashboard.yml file:

```
(C:\Program Files\Anaconda3) C:\Users\TO3THY0>conda-env  export -n DataScience > env_dashboard.yml
```

And then I want to create a new environment called "Dashboard" from that file. However I get an error:

```
(C:\Program Files\Anaconda3) C:\Users\TO3THY0>conda env create -n Dashboard -f env_dashboard.yml
Using Anaconda API: https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata ......
WARNING: The remote server could not find the noarch directory for the
requested channel with url: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Temp/AnacondaPlugin501

It is possible you have given conda an invalid channel. Please double-check
your conda configuration using `conda config --show`.

If the requested url is in fact a valid conda channel, please request that the
channel administrator create `noarch/repodata.json` and associated
`noarch/repodata.json.bz2` files, even if `noarch/repodata.json` is empty.
$ mkdir noarch
$ echo '{}' > noarch/repodata.json
$ bzip2 -k noarch/repodata.json
...............

ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - cuda 7.5 0
```

Removing cuda 7.5 0 from my env_dashboard.yml file doesn't help as the same error occurs again with the next package and so on. I tried to have a look at `conda config --show` but I don't know what to do with that information...

```
(C:\Program Files\Anaconda3) C:\Users\TO3THY0>conda config --show
add_anaconda_token: True
add_pip_as_python_dependency: True
allow_non_channel_urls: True
allow_softlinks: False
always_copy: False
always_softlink: False
always_yes: False
anaconda_upload: None
auto_update_conda: True
changeps1: True
channel_alias: https://conda.anaconda.org
channel_priority: True
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
client_ssl_cert: None
client_ssl_cert_key: None
clobber: False
create_default_packages: []
custom_channels:
  pkgs/main: https://repo.continuum.io/
  pkgs/free: https://repo.continuum.io/
  pkgs/r: https://repo.continuum.io/
  pkgs/pro: https://repo.continuum.io/
  pkgs/msys2: https://repo.continuum.io/
custom_multichannels:
  defaults: ["https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main", "https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free", "https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r", "https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro", "https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2"]
  local: []
default_channels:
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2
disallow: []
envs_dirs:
  - C:\Users\TO3THY0\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
  - C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs
  - C:\Users\TO3THY0\.conda\envs
force: False
json: False
local_repodata_ttl: 1
migrated_channel_aliases: []
non_admin_enabled: True
offline: False
path_conflict: clobber
pinned_packages: []
pkgs_dirs:
  - C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\pkgs
  - C:\Users\TO3THY0\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
proxy_servers: {}
quiet: False
remote_connect_timeout_secs: 9.15
remote_max_retries: 3
remote_read_timeout_secs: 60.0
rollback_enabled: True
shortcuts: True
show_channel_urls: None
ssl_verify: True
track_features: []
use_pip: True
verbosity: 0
```

This is my current conda install:

```
(C:\Program Files\Anaconda3) C:\Users\TO3THY0>conda info
Current conda install:

               platform : win-64
          conda version : 4.3.30
       conda is private : False
      conda-env version : 4.3.30
    conda-build version : 3.0.27
         python version : 3.6.3.final.0
       requests version : 2.18.4
       root environment : C:\Program Files\Anaconda3  (read only)
    default environment : C:\Program Files\Anaconda3
       envs directories : C:\Users\TO3THY0\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                          C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\TO3THY0\.conda\envs
          package cache : C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\TO3THY0\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch
            config file : C:\Users\TO3THY0\.condarc
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
             user-agent : conda/4.3.30 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17763
          administrator : False
```

This ist the env_dashboard.yml file:

```
name: DataScience
channels:
- msys2
- file:///C:/WINDOWS/Temp/AnacondaPlugin501
- plotly
- conda-forge
- defaults
dependencies:
- arviz=0.9.0=py_0
- cftime=1.2.0=py36h7725771_1
- convertdate=2.2.1=pyh9f0ad1d_0
- cython=0.29.20=py36h003fed8_0
- ephem=3.7.7.1=py36hfa6e2cd_0
- fbprophet=0.6=py36h6538335_0
- freetype=2.10.2=hd328e21_0
- holidays=0.10.2=pyh9f0ad1d_0
- kiwisolver=1.2.0=py36h246c5b5_0
- korean_lunar_calendar=0.2.1=pyh9f0ad1d_0
- libblas=3.8.0=14_mkl
- libcblas=3.8.0=14_mkl
- liblapack=3.8.0=14_mkl
- libpng=1.6.37=hfe6a214_1
- lunarcalendar=0.0.9=py_0
- m2w64-toolchain_win-64=2.4.0=0
- matplotlib=3.2.1=0
- matplotlib-base=3.2.1=py36hf0cddfc_0
- mkl-service=2.3.0=py36hfa6e2cd_0
- netcdf4=1.4.0=py36_0
- numpy=1.18.5=py36h4d86e3b_0
- pandas=1.0.5=py36hcc50265_0
- pymeeus=0.3.7=pyh9f0ad1d_0
- pystan=2.19.1.1=py36h12199cf_1
- python-dateutil=2.8.1=py_0
- python_abi=3.6=1_cp36m
- scipy=1.3.1=py36h29ff71c_0
- xarray=0.13.0=py_0
- _ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf=0.1.0=py36he6757f0_0
- alabaster=0.7.10=py36hcd07829_0
- anaconda=5.0.1=py36h8316230_2
- anaconda-client=1.6.5=py36hd36550c_0
- anaconda-navigator=1.6.9=py36hc720852_0
- anaconda-project=0.8.0=py36h8b3bf89_0
- argh=0.26.2=py36_0
- asn1crypto=0.22.0=py36h8e79faa_1
- astroid=1.5.3=py36h9d85297_0
- astropy=2.0.2=py36h06391c4_4
- atomicwrites=1.4.0=py_0
- autopep8=1.4.4=py_0
- babel=2.5.0=py36h35444c1_0
- backcall=0.2.0=py_0
- backports=1.0=py36h81696a8_1
- backports.shutil_get_terminal_size=1.0.0=py36h79ab834_2
- bcrypt=3.1.7=py36he774522_1
- beautifulsoup4=4.6.0=py36hd4cc5e8_1
- bitarray=0.8.1=py36h6af124b_0
- bkcharts=0.2=py36h7e685f7_0
- blas=1.0=mkl
- blaze=0.11.3=py36h8a29ca5_0
- bleach=2.0.0=py36h0a7e3d6_0
- bokeh=0.12.10=py36h0be3b39_0
- boto=2.48.0=py36h1a776d2_1
- bottleneck=1.2.1=py36hd119dfa_0
- brotlipy=0.7.0=py36he774522_1000
- bzip2=1.0.6=vc14hdec8e7a_1
- ca-certificates=2017.08.26=h94faf87_0
- cachecontrol=0.12.3=py36hfe50d7b_0
- certifi=2017.7.27.1=py36h043bc9e_0
- cffi=1.10.0=py36hae3d1b5_1
- chardet=3.0.4=py36h420ce6e_1
- click=6.7=py36hec8c647_0
- cloudpickle=1.4.1=py_0
- clyent=1.2.2=py36hb10d595_1
- colorama=0.3.9=py36h029ae33_0
- comtypes=1.1.2=py36heb9b3d1_0
- conda-verify=2.0.0=py36h065de53_0
- console_shortcut=0.1.1=h6bb2dd7_3
- contextlib2=0.5.5=py36he5d52c0_0
- cryptography=2.9.2=py36h7a1dbc1_0
- curl=7.55.1=vc14hdaba4a4_3
- cycler=0.10.0=py36h009560c_0
- cytoolz=0.8.2=py36h547e66e_0
- dash=1.4.1=py_0
- dash-core-components=1.3.1=py_0
- dash-html-components=1.0.1=py_0
- dash-renderer=1.1.2=py_0
- dash-table=4.4.1=py_0
- dask=0.15.3=py36h396fcb9_0
- dask-core=0.15.3=py36hd651449_0
- datashape=0.5.4=py36h5770b85_0
- decorator=4.1.2=py36he63a57b_0
- diff-match-patch=20181111=py_0
- distlib=0.2.5=py36h51371be_0
- distributed=1.19.1=py36h8504682_0
- docutils=0.14=py36h6012d8f_0
- entrypoints=0.2.3=py36hfd66bb0_2
- et_xmlfile=1.0.1=py36h3d2d736_0
- fastcache=1.0.2=py36hffdae1b_0
- filelock=2.0.12=py36hd7ddd41_0
- flake8=3.5.0=py36_1
- flask=1.1.2=py_0
- flask-compress=1.5.0=py_0
- flask-cors=3.0.3=py36h8a3855d_0
- future=0.18.2=py36_1
- get_terminal_size=1.0.0=h38e98db_0
- gevent=1.2.2=py36h342a76c_0
- glob2=0.5=py36h11cc1bd_1
- greenlet=0.4.12=py36ha00ad21_0
- h5py=2.7.0=py36hfbe0a52_1
- hdf4=4.2.13=h712560f_2
- hdf5=1.10.1=vc14hb361328_0
- heapdict=1.0.0=py36h21fa5f4_0
- html5lib=0.999999999=py36ha09b1f3_0
- icc_rt=2019.0.0=h0cc432a_1
- icu=58.2=vc14hc45fdbb_0
- idna=2.6=py36h148d497_1
- imageio=2.2.0=py36had6c2d2_0
- imagesize=0.7.1=py36he29f638_0
- importlib-metadata=1.7.0=py36_0
- importlib_metadata=1.7.0=0
- intel-openmp=2018.0.0=hcd89f80_7
- intervaltree=3.0.2=py_0
- ipykernel=5.3.0=py36h5ca1d4c_0
- ipython=7.16.1=py36h5ca1d4c_0
- ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py36h3c5d0ee_0
- ipywidgets=7.0.0=py36h2e74ada_0
- isort=4.2.15=py36h6198cc5_0
- itsdangerous=0.24=py36hb6c5a24_1
- jdcal=1.3=py36h64a5255_0
- jedi=0.15.2=py36_0
- jinja2=2.11.2=py_0
- jpeg=9b=vc14h4d7706e_1
- jsonschema=2.6.0=py36h7636477_0
- jupyter=1.0.0=py36h422fd7e_2
- jupyter_client=6.1.3=py_0
- jupyter_console=5.2.0=py36h6d89b47_1
- jupyter_core=4.6.3=py36_0
- jupyterlab=0.27.0=py36h34cc53b_2
- jupyterlab_launcher=0.4.0=py36h22c3ccf_0
- keyring=21.2.1=py36_0
- krb5=1.18.2=hc04afaa_0
- lazy-object-proxy=1.3.1=py36hd1c21d2_0
- libcurl=7.71.0=h2a8f88b_0
- libiconv=1.15=vc14h29686d3_5
- libnetcdf=4.5.0=h1f49dca_7
- libpython=2.1=py36_0
- libsodium=1.0.18=h62dcd97_0
- libspatialindex=1.9.3=h33f27b4_0
- libssh2=1.9.0=h7a1dbc1_1
- libtiff=4.0.8=vc14h04e2a1e_10
- libxml2=2.9.4=vc14h8fd0f11_5
- libxslt=1.1.29=vc14hf85b8d4_5
- llvmlite=0.20.0=py36_0
- locket=0.2.0=py36hfed976d_1
- lockfile=0.12.2=py36h0468280_0
- lxml=4.1.0=py36h0dcd83c_0
- lzo=2.10=vc14h0a64fa6_1
- markupsafe=1.0=py36h0e26971_1
- mccabe=0.6.1=py36hb41005a_1
- menuinst=1.4.10=py36h42196fb_0
- mistune=0.7.4=py36h4874169_0
- mkl=2019.4=245
- mpmath=0.19=py36he326802_2
- msgpack-python=0.4.8=py36h58b1e9d_0
- multipledispatch=0.4.9=py36he44c36e_0
- navigator-updater=0.1.0=py36h8a7b86b_0
- nbconvert=5.3.1=py36h8dc0fde_0
- nbformat=4.4.0=py36h3a5bc1b_0
- networkx=2.0=py36hff991e3_0
- nltk=3.2.4=py36hd0e0a39_0
- nose=1.3.7=py36h1c3779e_2
- notebook=5.0.0=py36hd9fbf6f_2
- numba=0.35.0=np113py36_10
- numexpr=2.6.2=py36h7ca04dc_1
- numpydoc=0.7.0=py36ha25429e_0
- odo=0.5.1=py36h7560279_0
- olefile=0.44=py36h0a7bdd2_0
- openpyxl=2.4.8=py36hf3b77f6_1
- openssl=1.1.1g=he774522_0
- packaging=16.8=py36ha0986f6_1
- pandoc=1.19.2.1=hb2460c7_1
- pandocfilters=1.4.2=py36h3ef6317_1
- paramiko=2.4.2=py36_0
- parso=0.5.2=py_0
- partd=0.3.8=py36hc8e763b_0
- path.py=10.3.1=py36h3dd8b46_0
- pathlib2=2.3.0=py36h7bfb78b_0
- pathtools=0.1.2=py_1
- patsy=0.4.1=py36h42cefec_0
- pep8=1.7.0=py36h0f3d67a_0
- pexpect=4.8.0=py36_0
- pickleshare=0.7.4=py36h9de030f_0
- pip=9.0.1=py36hadba87b_3
- pkginfo=1.4.1=py36hb0f9cfa_1
- plotly=4.8.1=py_0
- pluggy=0.13.1=py36_0
- ply=3.10=py36h1211beb_0
- progress=1.3=py36hbeca8d3_0
- prompt-toolkit=3.0.5=py_0
- prompt_toolkit=1.0.15=py36h60b8f86_0
- psutil=5.7.0=py36he774522_0
- py=1.4.34=py36ha4aca3a_1
- pyasn1=0.4.8=py_0
- pycodestyle=2.3.1=py36h7cc55cd_0
- pycosat=0.6.2=py36hf17546d_1
- pycparser=2.18=py36hd053e01_1
- pycrypto=2.6.1=py36he68e6e2_1
- pycurl=7.43.0.5=py36h7a1dbc1_0
- pydocstyle=5.0.2=py_0
- pyflakes=1.6.0=py36h0b975d6_0
- pygments=2.2.0=py36hb010967_0
- pylint=1.7.4=py36ha4e6ded_0
- pynacl=1.4.0=py36h62dcd97_0
- pyodbc=4.0.17=py36h0006bc2_0
- pyopenssl=17.2.0=py36h15ca2fc_0
- pyparsing=2.2.0=py36h785a196_1
- pyqt=5.9.2=py36h6538335_2
- pysocks=1.6.7=py36h698d350_1
- pytables=3.4.2=py36h71138e3_2
- pytest=3.2.1=py36h753b05e_1
- python=3.6.3=h9e2ca53_1
- python-jsonrpc-server=0.3.4=py_0
- python-language-server=0.31.10=py36_0
- pytz=2017.2=py36h05d413f_1
- pywavelets=0.5.2=py36hc649158_0
- pywin32=221=py36h9c10281_0
- pywin32-ctypes=0.2.0=py36_1000
- pyyaml=5.3.1=py36he774522_0
- pyzmq=19.0.1=py36ha925a31_1
- qdarkstyle=2.8.1=py_0
- qt=5.9.7=vc14h73c81de_0
- qtawesome=0.7.2=py_0
- qtconsole=4.7.5=py_0
- qtpy=1.9.0=py_0
- requests=2.18.4=py36h4371aae_1
- retrying=1.3.3=py_2
- rope=0.10.5=py36hcaf5641_0
- rtree=0.9.4=py36h21ff451_1
- ruamel_yaml=0.11.14=py36h9b16331_2
- scikit-image=0.13.0=py36h6dffa3f_1
- scikit-learn=0.19.1=py36h53aea1b_0
- seaborn=0.8.0=py36h62cb67c_0
- setuptools=36.5.0=py36h65f9e6e_0
- simplegeneric=0.8.1=py36heab741f_0
- singledispatch=3.4.0.3=py36h17d0c80_0
- sip=4.19.8=py36h6538335_0
- six=1.11.0=py36h4db2310_1
- snowballstemmer=1.2.1=py36h763602f_0
- sortedcollections=0.5.3=py36hbefa0ab_0
- sortedcontainers=1.5.7=py36ha90ac20_0
- sphinx=1.6.3=py36h9bb690b_0
- sphinxcontrib=1.0=py36hbbac3d2_1
- sphinxcontrib-websupport=1.0.1=py36hb5e5916_1
- spyder=4.1.3=py36_0
- spyder-kernels=1.9.1=py36_0
- sqlalchemy=1.1.13=py36h5948d12_0
- sqlite=3.32.3=h2a8f88b_0
- statsmodels=0.8.0=py36h6189b4c_0
- sympy=1.1.1=py36h96708e0_0
- tblib=1.3.2=py36h30f5020_0
- testpath=0.3.1=py36h2698cfe_0
- tk=8.6.7=vc14hb68737d_1
- toolz=0.8.2=py36he152a52_0
- tornado=4.5.2=py36h57f6048_0
- traitlets=4.3.2=py36h096827d_0
- typing=3.6.2=py36hb035bda_0
- ujson=1.35=py36hfa6e2cd_0
- unicodecsv=0.14.1=py36h6450c06_0
- urllib3=1.22=py36h276f60a_0
- vc=14.1=h0510ff6_4
- vs2015_runtime=14.16.27012=hf0eaf9b_2
- watchdog=0.10.3=py36_0
- wcwidth=0.1.7=py36h3d5aa90_0
- webencodings=0.5.1=py36h67c50ae_1
- werkzeug=1.0.1=py_0
- wheel=0.29.0=py36h6ce6cde_1
- widgetsnbextension=3.0.2=py36h364476f_1
- win_inet_pton=1.0.1=py36he67d7fd_1
- win_unicode_console=0.5=py36hcdbd4b5_0
- wincertstore=0.2=py36h7fe50ca_0
- wrapt=1.10.11=py36he5f5981_0
- xlrd=1.1.0=py36h1cb58dc_1
- xlsxwriter=1.0.2=py36hf723b7d_0
- xlwings=0.11.4=py36hd3cf94d_0
- xlwt=1.3.0=py36h1a4751e_0
- yaml=0.1.7=vc14hb31d195_1
- yapf=0.30.0=py_0
- zeromq=4.3.2=ha925a31_2
- zict=0.1.3=py36h2d8e73e_0
- zipp=3.1.0=py_0
- zlib=1.2.11=vc14h1cdd9ab_1
- altair=1.2.0=py36_0
- anyqt=0.0.8=py36_0
- commonmark=0.7.4=py36hde19d58_0
- cuda=7.5=0
- cudatoolkit=8.0=1
- dill=0.2.7.1=py36hf552773_0
- httplib2=0.10.3=py36_0
- keras=2.0.6=py36_0
- lasagne=0.1=py35_0
- opencv=3.2.0=np113py36_204
- orange3=3.5.0=np112py36_0
- pil=1.1.7=py27_0
- pillow=4.2.1=py36_1
- protobuf=3.5.2=py36_vc14_0
- pygame=1.9.2a0=py35_0
- pyqtgraph=0.10.0=py36_0
- scrapy=1.4.0=py36_0
- simplejson=3.11.1=py36_0
- tensorflow=1.3.0=py36_0
- theano=0.9.0=py36_2
- m2w64-binutils=2.25.1=5
- m2w64-bzip2=1.0.6=6
- m2w64-crt-git=5.0.0.4636.2595836=2
- m2w64-gcc=5.3.0=6
- m2w64-gcc-ada=5.3.0=6
- m2w64-gcc-fortran=5.3.0=6
- m2w64-gcc-libgfortran=5.3.0=6
- m2w64-gcc-libs=5.3.0=7
- m2w64-gcc-libs-core=5.3.0=7
- m2w64-gcc-objc=5.3.0=6
- m2w64-gmp=6.1.0=2
- m2w64-headers-git=5.0.0.4636.c0ad18a=2
- m2w64-isl=0.16.1=2
- m2w64-libiconv=1.14=6
- m2w64-libmangle-git=5.0.0.4509.2e5a9a2=2
- m2w64-libwinpthread-git=5.0.0.4634.697f757=2
- m2w64-make=4.1.2351.a80a8b8=2
- m2w64-mpc=1.0.3=3
- m2w64-mpfr=3.1.4=4
- m2w64-pkg-config=0.29.1=2
- m2w64-toolchain=5.3.0=7
- m2w64-tools-git=5.0.0.4592.90b8472=2
- m2w64-windows-default-manifest=6.4=3
- m2w64-winpthreads-git=5.0.0.4634.697f757=2
- m2w64-zlib=1.2.8=10
- msys2-conda-epoch=20160418=1
- plotly-orca=1.3.1=1
- python-kaleido=0.0.1=py36_0
- pip:
  - backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
  - et-xmlfile==1.0.1
  - ipython-genutils==0.2.0
  - jupyter-client==6.1.3
  - jupyter-console==5.2.0
  - jupyter-core==4.6.3
  - jupyterlab-launcher==0.4.0
  - kaleido==0.0.1
  - korean-lunar-calendar==0.2.1
  - ruamel-yaml==0.11.14
  - tables==3.4.2
  - win-inet-pton==1.0.1
  - win-unicode-console==0.5
prefix: C:\Users\TO3THY0\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\DataScience
```

Any help is highly appreciated!:)

Comment: What are the contents of the YAML file?

Comment: I edited the question and added the file

Comment: Perhaps a clone operation might be a simpler solution? `conda create --clone DataScience -n Dashboard` Although, I'm not sure what it'll do with those `pip`-installed packages.

Comment: I want to install the environment on another device and not on my own device. But on the other device I get the same error as here

Comment: What is the `file:///C:/WINDOWS/Temp/AnacondaPlugin501` channel?